# Add 2 spaces at the beggining of the elements in a list

Tags: python

I have the following list1:

```
['mama', 'papa', 'jose']
```

I would like to add 2 spaces to the beggining of each element in the list.
In order to do so what I tried was:

```
[x.rjust(2, ' ') for x in list1]
```

But the output remains the same:

```
['mama', 'papa', 'jose']
```

The desired output would be:

```
['  mama', '  papa', '  jose']
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `["  " + x for x in list1]` or `["  {}".format(x) for x in list1]`?

Comment: are the words in your list of same length ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you misunderstood what `rjust` does (check the [docs](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rjust.html)). If you simply want to add a prefix to the strings, you could use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (*Python 3.6>*):

```
l = ['mama', 'papa', 'jose']

[f' {s}' for s in l]
# ['  {}'.format(s) for s in l] for python 3.6<
[' mama', ' papa', ' jose']
```

Answer (score 0):

For rjust():

```
print([x.rjust(len(x) + 2) for x in ['mama', 'papa', 'jose']])
```

You need to pass the final length in rjust which I've done using len() to find current elements length ans then add 2 to it to get 2 spaces.

Another one liner:

```
print(["  "+x for x in ['mama', 'papa', 'jose'] ])
```

Or you can do this:

```
arr = ['mama', 'papa', 'jose']
for i in range(len(arr)):
  arr[i] = "  " + arr[i]
print(arr)
```

Pay attention to       `arr[i] = "  " + arr[i]`
 which adds the space to each entry in the list

Answer (score 0):

you can use map,lambda:

```
data = ['mama', 'papa', 'jose']

print (list(map(lambda x:  "  " + x, data)))
```

output:

```
['  mama', '  papa', '  jose']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
l = ['mama', 'papa', 'jose']
l = ["  "+x for x in l]
```